# How to split a columns based on the index of the string in the columns while using a efficient method to parse all the Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a column filled with a string value:

| col_1 |
| --- |
| 10500 |
| 25020 |
| 35640 |
| 45440 |
| 50454 |
| 62150 |
| 75410 |

I want to be able to create two other columns with strings values that have been splitted from the first. Also I want an efficient way to do that.

Supposed result :

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10500 | 10 | 500 |
| 25020 | 25 | 020 |
| 35640 | 35 | 640 |
| 45440 | 45 | 440 |
| 50454 | 50 | 454 |
| 62150 | 62 | 150 |
| 75410 | 75 | 410 |

So far I was trying to go with vectorization, but hasn't been able to implement it yet.

For the split part, I parse the row (with iterows, and I know that iterows has to be avoid as much as possible.) and create a list that can be used to populate the new tabs, but in my opinion this way is a too archaic.

Also, how can I efficiently, modify each cell ? Like adding a comma, or operating on them ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str` accessor:

```
df = df.join(df['col_1'].astype(str).str.extract('(?P<col_2>\d{2})(?P<col_3>\d{3})'))
print(df)

# Output:
   col_1 col_2 col_3
0  10500    10   500
1  25020    25   020
2  35640    35   640
3  45440    45   440
4  50454    50   454
5  62150    62   150
6  75410    75   410
```

Or simple in few steps:

```
df['col_1'] = df['col_1'].astype(str)
df['col_2'] = df['col_1'].str[:2]
df['col_3'] = df['col_1'].str[2:]
print(df)

# Output
   col_1 col_2 col_3
0  10500    10   500
1  25020    25   020
2  35640    35   640
3  45440    45   440
4  50454    50   454
5  62150    62   150
6  75410    75   410
```

Another example:

```
df['col_1'] = df['col_1'].astype(str)
df['col_4'] = df['col_1'].str[:2] + '-' + df['col_1'].str[2:]
print(df)

# Output
   col_1   col_4
0  10500  10-500
1  25020  25-020
2  35640  35-640
3  45440  45-440
4  50454  50-454
5  62150  62-150
6  75410  75-410
```

Comment: Nice, this looks like I want, I'm impressed that I can apply it on all the cells. Thank you Corralien.

However I'm still having trouble to get just the 2 first character and put it on a column.
In your example, the col_1 is equal to col_2.

Comment: I don't see the difference between your `col_1` and `col_2`, so I just copied the values :)

Comment: oh wait, my bad ! I rushed the post ahah, wait. It should be alright now x)

Comment: I just love the way you apply character on the values, I was looking for that all morning, and you make it look so simple !

Comment: I have another question now that you answered this one, what if I'd like to use a if on each value on the cell, so that if I found for instance a code 15 I replace it with another string. 
Or if I found a 15, I copy the entire row into another dataframe ?

Comment: You can use boolean mask and indexing like `df.loc[df['col_2'] == '25', 'col_3'] = '-'`

Comment: Okay I'm going to try things out ! Thank you very much Corralien, you're skilful !

Comment: I have added a post, on what i'm trying to do, I'm trying several methods, if you have a minut to check it out, it would be nice, thanks !
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70712543/how-to-parse-a-dataframe-efficiently-while-storing-data-specific-row-or-multi/70712586#70712586