# How to parse a dataframe efficiently, while storing data (specific row, or multiple rows) in others dataframe using a specific pattern?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

How to parse data on all rows, and use this row to populate other dataframes with data from multiple rows ?

I am trying to parse a csv file containing several data entry for training purpose as I am quite new to this technology.

My data consist in 10 columns, and hunderds of rows.
The first column is filled with a code that is either 10, 50, or 90.
Example :

Dataframe 1 :

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Power-220 |
| 90 | End |
| 10 | Power-290 |
| 90 | End |
| 10 | Power-445 |
| 90 | End |
| 10 | Power-390 |
| 50 | Clotho |
| 50 | Kronus |
| 90 | End |
| 10 | Power-550 |
| 50 | Ares |
| 50 | Athena |
| 50 | Artemis |
| 50 | Demeter |
| 90 | End |

And the list goes on..

On one hand I want to be able to read the first cell, and to populate another dataframe directly if this is a code 10.

On the other hand, I'd like to populate another dataframe with all the codes 50s, but I want to be able to get the data from the previous code 10, as it hold the type of Power that is used, and populate a new column on this dataframe.

The new data frames are supposed to look like this:

Dataframe 2 :

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Power-220 |
| 10 | Power-290 |
| 10 | Power-445 |
| 10 | Power-390 |
| 10 | Power-550 |

Dataframe 3 :

| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | Clotho | Power-390 |
| 50 | Kronus | Power-390 |
| 50 | Ares | Power-550 |
| 50 | Athena | Power-550 |
| 50 | Artemis | Power-550 |
| 50 | Demeter | Power-550 |

So far, I was using iterrows, and I've read everywhere that it was a bad idea.. but i'm struggling implementing another method..

In my code I just create two other dataframes, but I don't know yet a way to retrieve data from the previous cell. I would usually use a classic method, but I think it's rather archaic.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if (df.iat[index,0] == '10'):
      df2 = df2.append(df.loc[index], ignore_index = True)
    if (df.iat[index,0] == '50'):
      df3 = df3.append(df.loc[index], ignore_index = True)
```

Any ideas ?

(Update)

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by "but I want to be able to get the data from the previous code 10". At the moment you could just filter your original df once by 10 and once by 50 and make it a new df (don't need to iterate through then). But what happens to the row with the last col_1=='10' if you hit a line with col1=='50'....or better: what should happen ?

Comment: Have a look, I implemented examples to show what I want to accomplish. Thank you for your feedback, it wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For df2, it's pretty simple:

```
df2 = df.rename(columns={'Power/Character': 'Power'}) \
        .loc[df['Code'] == 10, :]
```

For df3, it's a bit more complex:

```
# Extract power and fill forward values
power = df.loc[df['Code'] == 10, 'Power/Character'].reindex(df.index).ffill()

df3 = df.rename(columns={'Power/Character': 'Character'}) \
        .assign(Power=power).loc[lambda x: x['Code'] == 50]
```

Output:

```
>>> df2
    Code      Power
0     10  Power-220
2     10  Power-290
4     10  Power-445
6     10  Power-390
10    10  Power-550

>>> df3
    Code Character      Power
7     50    Clotho  Power-390
8     50    Kronus  Power-390
11    50      Ares  Power-550
12    50    Athena  Power-550
13    50   Artemis  Power-550
14    50   Demeter  Power-550
```

Comment: Damn, it looks neat ! I'll try this right away. I need to get as skilled as you !

Comment: For the df3, i'm having trouble, I'll try to find a solution with what you gave me. If I'm really realy stuck, I'll post another question ahah! Have a good evening !

Comment: What is your problem with df3?

Comment: I try with my data, and my code, but it doesn't work exactly like yours, I don't know why yet, but my Power is being replaced by something else, I must be doing something wrong... 
This all, codes, and Power/Character, is just an example of what I want to do, so I don't just need to copy paste ahah, If i'm super stuck I'll add a comment.

Comment: I know now !!! I know why it doesn't work ! I made a mistake on the example

Comment: Sorry for notifying so fast, but I need to use my brain.. I'm sure I can do it, you already did the hardest part Thank you very much Corralien

Edit: I did it ! It works ! Your method is really awesome, it's clear, and fast. I love it.

Comment: Glad to read that. Try this code for a better visualization of your data: `df.assign(index=df.groupby('0').cumcount()).pivot('index', '0', '1').ffill()`

Comment: I have another question regarding the df3 method: 

# Extract power and fill forward values
power = df.loc[df['Code'] == 10, 'Power/Character'].reindex(df.index).ffill()

df3 = df.rename(columns={'Power/Character': 'Character'}) \
        .assign(Power=power).loc[lambda x: x['Code'] == 50]

Edit: I found the solution, you just need to create a new parameter

Comment: Hello @Corralien, today I come with a new question on the kinda same problem x). If you have any ideas, here is my post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70753923/how-to-retrieve-the-last-value-of-a-cell-dynamically-while-parsing-each-rows-of

Answer (score 1):

You could simply copy the required rows to another dataframe,

```
df2 = df[df.col_1 == '10'].copy()
```

This will make a new dataframe `df2` that contains only the rows from column `col_1` that fits some criteria. The `copy()` function guarantees that the two dataframes are not identical, and changes in one do not affect the other.

If `df2` already exists, you can concatenate them

```
df2 = pd.concat([df2, df[df.col_1 == '10'].copy()])
```

Comment: Okay, I've seen this method, i'll try it out, any idea on the data that I can get from the other rows ?